# How to sort 1 column in the python matrix in ascending order by bubble?

Tags: python, sorting, matrix

I can't sort 1 column in ascending order, can you help?
[image]

```
def sort():
  for i in range(n-1):
    for j in range(n-i-1):
      if j==0:
        if A[i][j]>A[i+1][j]:                
          w=A[i][j]
          A[i][j]=A[i+1][j]
          A[i+1][j]=w
  for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
      print('%0.3f'%(A[i][j]),end=' ')
    print()
  return A 
A=sort()
print()
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Read: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

```
def bubble_sort(matrix):
    n = len(matrix)
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n-i-1):
            if matrix[j][0] > matrix[j+1][0]:
                # swap rows j and j+1
                matrix[j], matrix[j+1] = matrix[j+1], matrix[j]
    return matrix

# example:
A = [[3.2, 1.5, 2.1],
     [2.8, 0.9, 1.3],
     [5.6, 4.1, 6.2]]

A_sorted = bubble_sort(A)

for row in A_sorted:
    for element in row:
        print(f"{element:.3f}", end=" ")
    print()
```

Output:

```
2.800 0.900 1.300 
3.200 1.500 2.100 
5.600 4.100 6.200
```

Comment: OP asks - *How to sort ONE column...*   And just post code w/o any explanations won't help.

Answer (score 1):

Question was: How to sort 1 column in the python matrix in ascending order by bubble?

- using the *array[row][**col**]* as the format, you should set the
  **col**umn to the value of the *to be sorted column*. That part should be 'fixed' during the sorting algorithm.
- using bubble sort, the end condition 'sorted', is when there is no longer a swap
  needed in bubble loop.

Using your provided code, I firstly simplify the sort for one dimension of the array. (Then there is no column or row distiction)

- variable swap indicates that a swap happened. Initial condition swap=1 to
  assume an unsorted array.
- used j to indicate the neighbour of i (j=i+1), following bubble logic.

```py
def sort():
    swap=1                      #assume unsorted input
    while swap==1:              # while unsorted
        swap=0                  #   assumed to be sorted after below loop
        for i in range(0,n-1):  #       from begin to the end-1 of the array
            j=i+1               #           set j to i+1 as the neighbour to compare
            if (A[i]>A[j]):     #           compare the two neigbours if swap is needed
                w=A[i]          #               swap needed, remember this value in w
                A[i]=A[j]       #               assign
                A[j]=w          #               assign then using w
                swap=1          #               no longer assume we are sorted, signal we swapped

    for i in range(n):
        print('%0.3f' %(A[i]),end=' ')
        print()
    return A

# Input
n=5
A = [ 5,4,3,2,1 ]

# Call function
sort()
print()
```

To extend the above example, you should only add the column indicator to all the array references.

```py
def sort():
    swap=1
    while swap==1:
        swap=0
        for i in range(n-1):
            j=i+1
            if (A[i][col]>A[j][col]):
                w=A[i][col]
                A[i][col]=A[j][col]
                A[j][col]=w
                swap=1;


    for i in range(n):
        for columns in range(n):
            print('%0.3f' %(A[i][columns]),end=' ')
        print()
    return A

n=5                 # Arr
col=0               # which column to sort
A = [[ 3,4,5,2,1 ] ,
     [ 5,4,3,2,1 ] ,
     [ 1,4,5,2,1 ] ,
     [ 2,4,3,2,1 ],
     [ 4,4,5,2,1 ] ]

sort()
print()
```

Good luck.

ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort